# is it OK to use property setter on private variables in python?

Tags: python, class, oop, object

In the following code snippet, I use a setter on the x attribute (which I'd like to keep private)

```
class test:

def __init__(self, pos, x):

    self._pos = pos
    self.x = x       # Want to be a private variable, eg. self._x


@property
def x(self):
    return self._x


@x.setter
def x(self, x):
    # Logic for setting x
    if self._pos == 'long':
        self._x = -1 * abs(x)
    elif self._pos == 'short':
        self._x = abs(x)
    else:
        raise ValueError('$$ pos must be long or short')
```

The problem is I end up with TWO attributes , self.x AND self._x . Since I want x to be private - I'd like to only have self._x (and discard self.x) . What's missing in the code ?

Comment: If you want it to be private, why do you have the `x` property at all? Why not just remove all that?

Comment: @user2357112 so that's what I'm wondering , do you need property on privates ?

Comment: @user2357112 you could use `def _x(self, x):` to show that it is "private", and maybe this is a good use-case for double-underscores, although I might use something like `self._x_` instead. They way I think of it, `property` is for encapsulation, but I may want encapsulation with a variable that is not part of the public api.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga is it fair to say a private variable is automatically encapsulated ?

Comment: @thomas.mac I suppose, I guess what I may mean is actually *information hiding*, that is according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_hiding): " principle of segregation of the design decisions in a computer program that are most likely to change, thus protecting other parts of the program from extensive modification if the design decision is changed. The protection involves providing a stable interface which protects the remainder of the program from the implementation (the details that are most likely to change)."

Comment: @thomas.mac IOW, let's say I never want to set a variable to a value higher than 42, then instead of using `if x < 42: self.x = x` in every method, I instead "hide" this in a setter. Python `property`'s just let you do this while maintaining a clean-looking syntax, and not forcing you to write boilerplate getters and setters and you can add them later without breaking the interface due to the magic of the descriptor protocol! Whether an attribute is part of the public API or not, I may want this regardless